# Getting an "overlap" effect with Bootstrap divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a full-width row and I want to have an image that extends a bit outside the top and bottom boundaries of the row, so as to look like a sticker holding a ribbon to the website. How do I achieve this "overlap" effect in CSS?

As far as I can tell, you can nest divs within each other or float them side-by-side, but you can't put a taller div on top of a thinner one and get this overlap effect to work. What am I missing?

I'm using Bootstrap... if there is some kind of grid-based solution to this that would be awesome.

EDIT: Code! Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="row-fluid redRibbon">
        <div class="bodyContainer">
            <img id="isocert" src="img/isocert.png">
        </div>
</div>
```

And relevant CSS (row-fluid is a default class in Bootstrap):

```
.bodyContainer{
            padding: 15px;
            width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
        }    
.redRibbon{
            background-color: #AF002A;
            color: white;
        }

#isocert{
            overflow: visible;
        }
```

I would post a picture but I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: `position:relative`?

Comment: paste some code Mike.. We can't see it, it's harder to help. Why make it hard for us Mike?

Comment: You could make a sketch of what you want, because I'm not pretty sure if I understand your question

Comment: As others have said, you need to post some code in order to get help here. Sounds like it will be a positioning issue though. Position relative on your containing div and absolute on the element you want to be specifically positioned.

Comment: Added some code! Also I see what you're going with with the absolute positioning on the element but doesn't that position relative to the top of the document? This entire setup will be about halfway down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `.row` the style or CSS rule `position: relative;` and now give your image you want to overlap that row `position: absolute;` but keep it placed inside the row. Now it will be placed relative to your `.row` but you can adjust its position with the CSS attributes `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. Furthermore you can make it bigger than the row (via CSS or image attributes) and it will not influence the dimensions of your `.row`. Should it be cut by an other element you can give it an higher `z-index`. With this values you should be able to get your desired effect.

**EDIT**

 So your code could look like something like this in the end:

```
.bodyContainer{
            padding: 15px;
            width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
        }    
.redRibbon{
            margin-top: 200px;
            background-color: #AF002A;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
        }

#isocert{
            overflow: visible;
            position: absolute;
            top: -50px;
        }
```

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/L1wn66v8/

Answer (score 0):

One option (in the absence of any supplied code) is to position the image with relative positioning.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.clipartpal.com/_thumbs/pd/education/award_ribbon_blue_T.png" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus hic dicta dignissimos consequuntur mollitia enim fuga inventore tempore totam ad libero eveniet voluptatum iusto quis unde deleniti doloribus quos veniam perspiciatis rerum in cum
    facilis maxime. Reiciendis corporis dolor tenetur at sunt quidem asperiores natus ad soluta fuga maiores expedita vero explicabo rem consequuntur accusantium similique alias odio cupiditate quaerat eligendi! Laborum illum earum pariatur minus sunt
    eaque praesentium cum libero nihil voluptatibus dolorem eum. Eveniet nobis mollitia</p>
</div>
```

Note that the text continues to wrap around the image **as though it was still in the same place**. The element is only moved **visually**, any other elements will still treat it as though it had not been moved.

*As an alternative*, you could position it **absolutely, but relative to the parent**. In this case, the element is taken out of the flow and other elements will **not** react to it in the same way..

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.clipartpal.com/_thumbs/pd/education/award_ribbon_blue_T.png" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus hic dicta dignissimos consequuntur mollitia enim fuga inventore tempore totam ad libero eveniet voluptatum iusto quis unde deleniti doloribus quos veniam perspiciatis rerum in cum
    facilis maxime. Reiciendis corporis dolor tenetur at sunt quidem asperiores natus ad soluta fuga maiores expedita vero explicabo rem consequuntur accusantium similique alias odio cupiditate quaerat eligendi! Laborum illum earum pariatur minus sunt
    eaque praesentium cum libero nihil voluptatibus dolorem eum. Eveniet nobis mollitia</p>
  </div
```